# Backup Full of a database on a standby node in Cluster Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, backup

I am trying to get a full backup from a standby node in a postgresql cluster but when I run the script I get the following error

```
pg_dump -U userbackup -W databasename > databasename.sql
```

pg_dump: When you dump the contents of the "" table failed: PQgetResult() failed.
pg_dump: error: Server error message: ERROR:  canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL:  The user query might have needed to see row versions that need to be removed.

With what I researched, I modified the hot_standby_feedback parameter but I still can’t generate the backup. Can you advise me if there is a parameter that I need to modify to be able to eject it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to increase [`max_standby_streaming_delay`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-MAX-STANDBY-STREAMING-DELAY) on the standby server. That will give your `pg_dump` more time to finish, but will potentially delay replication. See [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/streaming-replication-conflicts-in-postgresql/) for details.